# Can you write in a filter to exclude certain folders when running a Get-ChildItem to compile a list of folder sizes?

Tags: powershell

I am needing to get a csv file of a group of subfolders within a directory that labels each folder and it's size (preferibly in GB's).

So far, I have this:

```
$targetPath = '\\folderpath\users'
(Get-ChildItem $targetPath -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
```

There is a folder that resides within each subfolder in the directory, that I do not have permissions/access to so any time I run the script, I get an access denied error.

The folder path looks like this:

```
'\\folderPath\users\.V6'
```

Is it possible to write in an exclusion for the above folder and have the script skip it when gathering the size of each of the folders within the Users file?  The size of the folder is tiny so it will not have an impact on the results.

Comment: Regardless of the error it should continue on. To hide the error add -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to the Get-ChildItem command

Comment: Ditto to what Doug said, but know, Get-ChildItem has a -Include and -Exclude param.

Answer (score 0):

Get-ChildItem has a -Include and -Exclude param.

> -Exclude <String[]> Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet excludes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter.  Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcards are permitted.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-ChildItem
Get-Childitem -System -File -Recurse
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory,!Directory+Hidden
dir -att !d,!d+h
dir -ad
Get-ChildItem -File -Attributes !ReadOnly -path C:\ps-test
get-childitem . -include *.txt -recurse -force
get-childitem c:\windows\logs\* -include *.txt -exclude A*
get-childitem -name
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online
```